# create counter variable with Boolean condition using value from the previous row

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr

I want to create a **counter variable c** based on the **group** **variable user** and **True or False** **variable B**.

```
DT <- data.table(time=c(1,2,3,1,1,2,3,1,1,1),user=c(1,1,1,2,3,3,3,4,4,5), B=c('t','f','t','f','f','t','t','t','t','t'))
DT
```

The **desired output** of variable c

```
    time user B C
 1:    1    1 t 1
 2:    2    1 f 1
 3:    3    1 t 2
 4:    1    2 f 0
 5:    1    3 f 0
 6:    2    3 t 1
 7:    3    3 t 2
 8:    1    4 t 1 
 9:    2    4 t 2
10:    1    5 t 1
```

variable c is a counter within the group when B is true.  **The logic (NOT code) of variable c** is as follow. The sequence do matter as you can see from the time variable.

```
 if time=1 and b=='f' {c=0}
    else 
    {
      if b=='t'{c=previous[c]+1} 
      else {c=previous[c]}
    }


  #if there is no variable b, the counter can be created using dplyr:     
          group_by(user)%>%mutate(c=seq_along(user))
  #or data.table
         DT[, c := seq_len(.N), by = user]
  # we can use data.table function shift() combined with for loop but i want to avoid for loop, it is slow and I have 300,000 rows.
```

Comment: You should store B as a logical vector, not with your own custom codes for true and false. Try `DT[, B := B == "t"]`

Comment: I am a little lost on your code. You are storing B as logical ,right?@Frank

Comment: The code overwrites your B column with one that has a `class` of `logical`. Read docs at `?class` and `?logical` if you're not clear on what I mean.

Comment: **"Create a cumulative counter of B==True, within each group of user"**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We group by 'user', `cumsum` the logical vector (`B=="t"`) and assign (`:=` ) the output to 'C'.

```
DT[, C:= cumsum(B=="t"), by = user]
DT
#    time user B C
# 1:    1    1 t 1
# 2:    2    1 f 1
# 3:    3    1 t 2
# 4:    1    2 f 0
# 5:    1    3 f 0
# 6:    2    3 t 1
# 7:    3    3 t 2
# 8:    1    4 t 1
# 9:    2    4 t 2
#10:    1    5 t 1
```

---

The same logic can be applied to `dplyr` methods

```
library(dplyr)
DT %>%
   group_by(user) %>%
   mutate(C = cumsum(B == "t"))
```

Comment: Is there anyway to incorporate the shift(), in this day, the code would be more general?

Comment: @Phdami If you need to `shift` the 'C' column, `DT[, paste0("Clag", 1:2) := shift(C, 1:2), by = user]`

Comment: Hi I need to use value form previous row a lot with different conditions. i am just wondering, if there is a way to use the value from the previous row  to create the counter instead of cumsum. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Phdami I am not sure I understand your question.  Can you post that as a new question?

Comment: I have updated the questions. What if the time variables are the same for some rows(it does not mean the rows are duplicate because it might have other columns are different but I did not show here.)

Comment: @Phdami That is a different question and I answered for the question you posted.  Please do post as a new question.

Comment: sure. I will post a new one.

Comment: this is the new question. thank you! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38900796/counter-variables-with-multiple-conditions

Answer (score 1):

If you use for loop for the same the, syntax for the following logic would be

```
for(i in unique(DT$user)){
  DT$c[DT$user==i] <- cumsum(DT$B[DT$user==i]=="t")
}

print(DT)

  time user B c
 1:    1    1 t 1
 2:    2    1 f 1
 3:    3    1 t 2
 4:    1    2 f 0
 5:    1    3 f 0
 6:    2    3 t 1
 7:    3    3 t 2
 8:    1    4 t 1
 9:    2    4 t 2
10:    1    5 t 1
```

Comment: Why would you initialize a numeric column to "" (a string)?

Comment: is for loop in data.table fast? or the same speed as r.base? I have over 300,000 rows in my data.

Comment: @Phdaml using base function can speed up, rather than using for loop

Comment: @Arunkumarmahesh I don't understand. What do you mean by using base function can speed up rather than for loop? You are using for loop, right? Is there any difference in terms of speed when you use for loop in data.table instead of data.frame?

Comment: @Phdaml when we use data.table the speed elapsed is 0.03sec, while in data.frame speed elapsed is 0.00 sec, so using data.frame is better than data.table

Comment: @Arunkumarmahesh  how big is the dataset you used for comparison?

Comment: @akrun the dataset which op has posted in this context

Comment: how can you generalise using that small dataset that `data.frame` is better than `data.table`.

Comment: @akrun In this context, i can justify data.frame is better than data.table as shown the speed elapsed in previous comments. In large data i may not justify the statement unless i run them

Comment: If you are using a small dataset, what is the point of comparison of speed anyways?

Comment: @akrun Yup its true, but as OP mentioned about the speed i need to compare in this context, can you justify which is the better one among these

Comment: It is pointless to compare a dataset of 10 rows for speed.  From the OP's comments on your post `have over 300,000 rows in my data`, I don't know how you are making the context?

Comment: @akrun As OP mentioned if we use 30,000 rows, which one is better in terms of speed do you have any idea

Comment: That is my point exactly, then why don't you test it on that size data and see if the data.frame is efficient or not.  he meant 300,000.

Comment: So, finally i got my conclusion from the following discussion that data.frame is better than data.table. data.table(user  system elapsed 1.60    0.26    1.87 ), data.frame(user  system elapsed 0.54    0.10    0.67) on 300,000 rows