# Create cumulative counter variable per-user, with multiple conditions

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr, cumulative-sum

I need to create a counter variable depending on three other variables.

This is an extension question of this one.[extension question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38559429/create-counter-variable-with-boolean-condition-using-value-from-the-previous-row)
Consider the situations of multiple consumers place order in Amazon. I want to count the successful order times by each user. If you have placed order successfully, the counter variable self plus one;if it is a failed order, the counter remains the same. Obviously, the counter variable will be depend on the time,order status and user.

Please consider the scenario of when t is the same but the order status is different,which does not mean the row is duplicate, it has other columns that are different.

```
DT <- data.table(time=c(1,2,2,2,1,1,2,3,1,1),user=c(1,1,1,1,2,3,3,3,4,4), order_status=c('f','f','t','t','f','f','t','t','t','t'))
DT
```

The desired counter output is as follow. The 'output' is the counter variable.

```
    time user order_status output
 1:    1    1            f      0
 2:    2    1            f      0
 3:    2    1            t      1
 4:    2    1            t      1
 5:    1    2            f      0
 6:    1    3            f      0
 7:    2    3            t      1
 8:    3    3            t      2
 9:    1    4            t      1
10:    1    4            t      1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main challenge here is to set the *first occurrence* of every combination of `time, user, order_status=='t'` to 1. Then it's a simple cumulative sum grouped by `user`.

Here are two ways to accomplish this using `data.table`:

**Method 1:**

```
DT[, id := 0L
  ][order_status == "t", id := c(1L, rep(0L, .N-1L)), by=names(DT)
   ][, id := cumsum(id), by=user]
```

The 2nd line here marks the first occurrence by `1` only when `order_status == "t"`.

A heavily commented production code of mine would look something like this:

```
DT[, id := 0L                       # set entire id col to 0
  ][order_status == "t",            # then, where order status is true
      id := c(1L, rep(0L, .N-1L)),  # set (or update) first value to 1
      by = names(DT)                # for every time,user,order_status
   ][, id := cumsum(id),            # then, get cumulative sum of id
       by = user]                   # for every user
```

---

**Method 2:** Using data.table's *join+update*:

```
DT[, id := 0L
  ][DT, id := as.integer(order_status == "t"), mult="first", on=names(DT)
   ][, id := cumsum(id), by=user]
```

The 2nd step here does the same as in method 1, but it directly identifies the first occurrence and updates it to `1` if `order_status == "t"` by performing an update on a join based subset. You can replace the `DT` on the inside with `unique(DT)` so as to remove redundancy.

If I've to, I'd say 1st method is more efficient, since creating a `rep()` for each group should be quite fast, as opposed to a join+update. But I find the 2nd method more understandable to identify as to what the *actual operation* is, which I think is more important if you were to look at your code several weeks after.

Comment: Instead of a join, maybe `which` is faster and equally readable? `DT[, v := 0L][DT[order_status == "t", which=TRUE], v := rleid(time), by=user]` The `rleid` there is awkward, but no harder to understand than a `cumsum` for me.

Comment: What is the 'L' in c(1L, rep(0L, .N-1L)?

Comment: @Frank, `DT[order_status == "t", which=TRUE]` is simply `which(order_status == "t")`, which is equivalent to `order_status == "t"` (`which` is used internally). Also, I don't think `rleid` is applicable here since an `f` after a `t` should maintain the value under `t` (although I'm not sure if it is a possible scenario for OP).

Comment: @Phdaml `1` is numeric/double type in R (takes 8 bytes of storage). `1L` sets type to integer (4 bytes). Check using `class(1)` and `class(1L)`.

Answer (score 2):

A simple approach using `data.table` is:

```
DT[,output := cumsum(order_status=="t" & !duplicated(cbind(time,user,order_status)))
   ,by=.(user)]

    time user order_status output
 1:    1    1            f      0
 2:    2    1            f      0
 3:    2    1            t      1
 4:    2    1            t      1
 5:    1    2            f      0
 6:    1    3            f      0
 7:    2    3            t      1
 8:    3    3            t      2
 9:    1    4            t      1
10:    1    4            t      1
```

This approach will basically fill in the last "t" value for any "f" values. If you want to make all "f" values 0, that is easy enough as well - just change the `by=...` to be `by=.(user,order_status)`.

Answer (score 1):

The most readable way is probably a subquery.

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
DT <- data.table(time=c(1,2,2,2,1,1,2,3,1,1),user=c(1,1,1,1,2,3,3,3,4,4), order_status=c('f','f','t','t','f','f','t','t','t','t'))
DT %>% left_join(
  DT %>%
    filter(order_status == "t") %>%
    group_by(user, time) %>%
    summarise() %>%
    arrange(time) %>%
    mutate(output = row_number()),
  by = c("user", "time")) %>%
  mutate(output = ifelse(is.na(output), 0, output))
```

NB using `tidyr` you can replace the last `mutate` by `replace_na(list(output = 0))`.